# Fourier transform of tempered function

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, fourier-transform

How can we prove that the Fourier transform of: 
$(1/|x|^\alpha)$ is $C(1/|\xi|)^{n-\alpha}$ as a tempered distribution (in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$) , where $C$ is a constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the Fourier transform of $f(\omega) = \frac{1}{|\mathbf{\omega}|^{\alpha}}$. This distribution is radial and homogeneous of degree $-\alpha$. You can use the scaling properties of the Fourier transform to show that this means that its Fourier transform is radial and homogeneous of degree $-n + \alpha$. Then you can show that this only happens when this Fourier transform is of the form $c_\alpha \frac{1}{|\mathbf{\xi}|^{n - \alpha}}$.

So it remains to determine $c_\alpha$. For this you can use Plancherel's theorem in conjunction with the fact that $e^{-\pi |\omega|^2}$ is its own Fourier transform, so that you have
$$\int_{R^n} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{\omega}|^{2\alpha}}e^{-\pi|\omega|^2}\,d\omega = 
c_{\alpha} \int_{R^n} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{\xi}|^{n - 2\alpha}}e^{-\pi|\xi|^2}\,d\xi$$ 
You can turn both integrals into one dimensional integrals using polar coordinates and then solve for $c_{\alpha}$. The result will be a ratio of gamma functions.

Comment: What are the scaling properties of Fourier transform?

Comment: @Math1995 Check this! http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node2.html  where it says "time and frequency scaling"